# Can I use one socket for the client?

Tags: python, sockets

My program is saying that clientsocket doesn't exist. Even though it has be defined in a different subprogram (that the user has to go through). So my question is do I have to have multiple sockets?

From what I can see, people usually close their sockets then make a new one, but I am wondering if I can just disconnect my socket and then connect it to a different server, this is so I can just define one socket at the start of my program.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  but I am wondering if I can just disconnect my socket and then connect it to a different server,

This is not possible with a TCP socket. You can only `connect` a socket once.

Comment: Right, I need a fix to the "socket is not defined" issue. I will send a pastebin link to my subprograms that handle connecting, recv, and sending messages: https://pastebin.com/0f4hz1pe

Comment: @NaNdy: your original question has been answered. What you are asking now is to fix your code which is a different question and thus should be asked as a new one. But it will not help to ask this question just by showing some code fragment taking out of context and with no description of what you expect it to do what you get instead.

Comment: Different question, fair point. Out of context code? No. It has all the code that handles sockets and sending/receiving.

Comment: @NaNdy: "It has all the code that handles sockets and sending/receiving"* - sure, but it has none of the expectations you have how this code should work and what it does instead and how it gets used from the rest of your application. This is context too.

Comment: Expectations have already been laid out . I want to send a message to the server. It doesn't matter what message, just a message. The context comes from this question (hence me not making another question out of it).